# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'trim')

Tags: undefined, hardhat

I have this section of code:

```
for (let i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    //trim address to make sure there are no trailing whitespaces
    const address = items[i].address.trim();
    const token_uri = `${TOKEN_BASE_URI}/${tokenId}.json`;
```

Every time I run it I get the error:

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'trim')

Could someone please tell me how to fix this, tia.

I tried adding various code snippets, defining the relevant const as a string, or as an empty string but nothing works. I don't know if I'm doing all the wrong things or I've done the right thing but the wrong way, but nothing has worked.

Comment: Object `items[i]` doesn't have a field named `address`.

Comment: You may wanna start with `console.log(items[i])` in order to find out which fields this object DOES have. It's pretty basic Javascript, really (i.e., not related to hardhat or anything like that).

Comment: learn some basic debugging skills, asking at SO is not one of them

Comment: if you don't tag it with a language you won't get much responds